# how to slow fast animation

Tags: rendering, animation

[image]

I was working on an animation which is a car moving on a path and found the animation too fast ,so i used time remapping to make it slower and i rendered it as PNG and used the video sequence editor to make an image strip and render them as a video, but the resulted video was too fast as if the time remapping has done nothing what shall i do?

Comment: You can adjust the evaluation time of the path in the properties panel Curve>>Path animation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eNu9.png

Comment: thanks, i will try it but isn't there any solution i can do when i add rendered images in the video sequence editor and render them as a video

Comment: you can decrease the frame rate but it will be laggy below 24 fps